# Increment variable from database value starts at 2 instead of 1 despite initial value being 0

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to retrieve an integer value from my database, increment the value by one and then update the relevant field in the database with the incremented value. This is to count the amount of times a user has entered an incorrect password. My problem is that the first time an incorrect password is entered, the field that counts the number of incorrect attempts is set to 2 rather than 1. If I then do another incorrect password attempt the value is set to 3, which tells me that it is increasing by 1 but for some reason the first attempt is counting twice. Any advice as to why this may be happening would be greatly appreciated!

The following code executes after a button click event:

```
Dim attempts As Integer = CInt(tblOfficialUser.Rows(0).Item("OfficialInvalidLoginNoAttempts"))
                            attempts += 1
                            UpdateOfficialUserAttempts(UserName, CByte(attempts), Nothing)
```

I have also tried:

```
If CInt(tblOfficialUser.Rows(0).Item("OfficialInvalidLoginNoAttempts")) = 1 Then
                                UpdateOfficialUserAttempts(UserName, CByte(2), Nothing)
                            ElseIf CInt(tblOfficialUser.Rows(0).Item("OfficialInvalidLoginNoAttempts")) = 2 Then
                                UpdateOfficialUserAttempts(UserName, CByte(3), Nothing)
                            Else
                                UpdateOfficialUserAttempts(UserName, CByte(1), Nothing)
                            End If
```

This has the exact same result as the previous code and I have also tried a case statement with the same result.

Answer (score 0):

As a first check I would check the value returned by 
`CInt(tblOfficialUser.Rows(0).Item("OfficialInvalidLoginNoAttempts"))`
to make sure it is returning `0`.

As you say your second example has the same problem, I would suspect it's returning `1`, not `0`.

Comment: http://imgur.com/xhzdKLe  <-- This is a screenshot of my code after I have placed a break point on the function and executed it. It shows that the attempts variable is initially set to 0 before the '+=1'. It is proving to be a very strange and frustrating bug.

Comment: @pault494 In that screenshot you haven't actually assigned a value to `attempts` and `Integer`s have a default value of 0. Breakpoint the next line, or simply step to the next statement to see the real value of `attempts`

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution to the problem. The function was being called twice; once in the html button on-click parameters and again in the code behind click event handler. Stupid mistake on my part but a lesson learned nonetheless.